# Maximum of two double data type values without using comparison operator

Tags: c

If the data type of two values is "double". Is there any way to get the maximum of two without using comparison operator such as if or "?". I just need a faster method.

Comment: I think there will always be a comparison somewhere. Why do you need this?

Comment: How have you determined that the cost of `if (a > b)` is the key bottleneck in your system?  It is highly improbable as the cause of your slowdown.

Comment: you can read memory from both doubles as long long and compare them

Comment: @osgx Beware of NaNs if you attempt this method.

Comment: How likely is it that any trick to avoid floating-point comparisons will end up being faster than an actual floating-point comparison? If there were a faster way to compare doubles, don't you think the implementation would be using it already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All modern floating point units on 32 or 64 bit CPUs can produce (at least) one add result per clock cycle, with a latency of a few clock cycles.  A floating point compare has the same performance as a floating point add. Therefore, you cannot speed up a floating point compare by using a combination of other floating point instructions, and using an integer compare fails in the case of NaNs.

If your compiler knows about conditional moves like `FCMOVcc` on x86, you can get the maximum of two floating point values without using a slow branch instruction.

Comment: Thankyou all the guys for being so helpful.I never expected so quick replies :)

Answer (score 6):

> I just need a faster method.

Faster than a compare? No way. Compare will just generate a highly-optimized machine instruction. Don't see how you improve on that.

But, here are some intellectual curiosities for your enjoyment.

Here's one way:

```
double max = 0.5 * (a + b + fabs(a - b));
```

Proof:

```
a >= b => a - b >= 0 
       => |a - b| = a - b 
       => a + b + |a - b| = a + b + a - b = 2a 
       => 0.5 * (a + b + |a - b|) = a

a < b => a - b < 0 
      => |a - b| = b - a 
      => a + b + |a - b| = a + b + b - a = 2b 
      => 0.5 * (a + b + |a - b|) = b
```

Note this suffers a weakness: it's can overflow.

Here's another:

```
double difference = a - b;
double sign = ((int)difference)>>63) & 1;
double max = a - difference * sign;
```

It's obvious what the intuition is here. We want to compute the sign of the difference (without using a compare), and use that sign to compute the max.

Proof:

```
a > b => a - b >= 0
      => difference >= 0
      => sign = 0
      => max = a - difference * sign = a - (a - b) * 0 = a
      => max = a

a < b => a - b < 0
      => difference < 0
      => sign = 1
      => max = a - difference * sign = a - (a - b) * 1 = a - a + b = b
      => max = b
```

Beware, 0 has two possible signs from +0d and -0d, but it doesn't matter! This too, can overflow, though.

Comment: 3 floating point addition/subtraction ops, a multiply, and an absolute value...it is clever arithmetic, but I don't see how it could be faster than a floating point comparison.  Also, in C (which the question is tagged as being), `abs()` comes from `<stdlib.h>` and is for integer values; `fabs()` comes from `<math.h>` and is for floating point values.

Comment: This is vulnerable to overflow.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: Of course it's not going to be faster. Nothing is going to be faster than a compare. Compare is just going to compile to a highly-optimized machine instruction.

Comment: And your updated answer addresses that which was the core of the question.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: Oh, I don't know about "core." Title and only question ask if it's possible. He merely states he needs something faster.

Comment: For your second method, starting with `a - b`...suppose `a` is a massive positive number, just smaller than the maximum possible `double`, and `b` is a massive negative number, just larger (less negative) than the most negative possible `double`.  Then the difference between `a` and `b` is too large to represent, so it will probably produce a positive infinity.  It also runs into the problem if the roles are reversed, generating a negative infinity.  (As to 'core' or not...it's probably best left as 'agreeing to differ'.  The updated answer addresses the issue, so you're good to go.)

Comment: If `a` is `1`, `b` is `0x1.5555555555555p+0`, and `0.5 * (a + b + fabs(a - b))` is evaluated using solely IEEE 754 double-precision, then the result is `0x1.5555555555554p+0`, which is not the maximum of `a` and `b`. The proof says “a + b + a – b = 2a”, but that is not true in floating-point arithmetic.

Comment: Thankyou all the guys for being so helpful.I never expected so quick replies :